# Where can I find an English translation of a Bön text called the Ma Gyud / Ma Gyudr (Mother Tantra)?

Tags: books, sleep, dreams, bon

There is a Bön text I found out about recently that I’ve spent a lot of time looking for but haven’t been able to find anywhere as an English translation.

The text is:

Ma Gyud / Ma Gyudr / Ma Rgyud (Mother Tantra). I think the full translation of the name of the book is: Mother Tantra: The Tantric Cycle of the Sun of Compassion (Ma rgyud thugs rje nyi ma'i rgyud skor). Or it might also be: Secret Mother Tantra Cycle (Ma rgyud gsang skor), which was first promulgated among humanity by the Royal Shen Milu Samleg / Samlek [Mi lus bsams legs]
I found references to the Mother Tantra in Tenzin Wangyal Rinpoche’s book “The Tibetan Yogas of Dream and Sleep”. I’ve also come across some more info about it and its structure here: http://www.surajamrita.com/bon/MotherTantra.html There might also be some other names for it here: http://drenpa-namkha.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/A-Title-of-mother-tantra.pdf

I’d really love to read and practice from the source material. I suspect, however, that there may not be an English translation of it available, as I haven’t found any traces of it online.

Would anyone be able to point me to a page or pdf online of this original text where it’s been translated, or send me a copy if you have one? Or alternatively, know of an English translation I could buy as a kindle or physical book?

Thanks in advance for any help!